# Android periodically setX/setY of View to new position and keep new position for 0.5 second

Tags: android, animation, view

i would like solve this scenario:
pseudo:

```
for i = 0; i < 10; i++ {
    view.setX(newXpos); //e.g. 100px
    view.setY(newYpos); //e.g. 200px
    save this position (100;200) on screen and apply FadeOut effect (500ms), but view have to ready for new iteration move to new position
}
```

The result: see short (500ms) history of View on X,Y coords.
I do not know, it's understandable?
I tried use `TranslateAnimation()` with `setFillAfter(true)`, but this move with original View.

For Android 5+
Thank you.